# How to insert from one table into another with additional combination values in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have two tables, and i want to insert from table 1 to table 2, the schema will be like

Table 1

```
[Id]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
[Name]    VARCHAR(140) NULL,
[Address] VARCHAR(140) NULL,
```

Table 2

```
[Id]          UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
[Name]        VARCHAR(140) NULL,
[Address]     VARCHAR(140) NULL, 
[Description] VARCHAR(140) NULL,
```

Here is what I tried:

```
INSERT INTO Table_2 (Id, Name, Address, Description) 
    SELECT * FROM Table_1
```

but I want `Description` in `Table_2` to be combination of `Name` and `Address`. So for example, if I have

```
Id    Name    Address
---------------------
1     John    NewYork
```

in `table_1`, I want to have

```
Id    Name     Address     Description
---------------------------------------
1     John     NewYork     John_NewYork
```

in `table_2`.

Is there anyway I can achieve this? Thank you

Comment: Yes its done easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I think you can do it like this

```
INSERT INTO Table_2 (Id, Name, Address, Description) 
SELECT Id, Name, Address, Name+'_'+Address FROM Table_1
```

Try that.